# Setting state with a function in another file

Tags: react-native

Without attempting to update my state, the initial `location` in state is presented correctly. When I set state using a helper function, nothing is displayed in my app. What am I doing wrong? Additionally, logging `props` inside `ShowLocation`'s `render()` shows that the `coords{lat:xx,long:xx}` are coming through correctly.

App.js

```
import * as helpers from './src/helpers';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = globals.initial_state;
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({location:helpers.getLocation()});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ShowLocation coords={this.state.location} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

ShowLocation.js

```
class ShowLocation extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>{this.props.coords.lat}, {this.props.coords.long}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
};
```

helpers.getLocation:

```
export function getLocation(){
    coords = {};
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
            coords['lat'] = position.coords.latitude
            coords['long'] = position.coords.longitude
        },
        (error) => this.setState({ navigatorError: error.message }),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
    return coords;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({ location: getLocation().bind(this) });
}
```

Or, same thing, but cleaner code:

```
constructor() {
  // other stuff
  this.getLocation = getLocation().bind(this)
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({ location: this.getLocation() });
}
```

Edit:

You must `import { getLocation} from 'path/of/file'`

Comment: `helpers.getLocation(...).bind is not a function`

Comment: Edited answer. You must import correctly your function. I was using the helps object you provided in your question

Comment: I have done that. I updated `App.js` in my question.